# Switch statement not working when using .includes()

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, switch-statement

```
client.on('chat', function(channel, userstate, message, self){



  switch(message){
    case message.includes(emotes[0]):
      numberOfEmotes[0]++;
      console.log("Emote0 has been used " + numberOfEmotes[0] + " time(s)");
      break;
    case message.includes(emotes[1]):
      numberOfEmotes[1]++;
      console.log("Emote1 has been used " + numberOfEmotes[1] + " time(s)");
      break;
    case message.includes(emotes[2]):
      numberOfEmotes[2]++;
      console.log("Emote2 has been used " + numberOfEmotes[2] + " time(s)");
      break;
    case message.includes(emotes[3]):
      numberOfEmotes[3]++;
      console.log("Emote3 has been used " + numberOfEmotes[3] + " time(s)");
      break;
  }

/*  if(message.includes(emotes[0])){
    numberOfEmotes[0]++;
    console.log("Emote0 has been used " + numberOfEmotes[0] + " time(s)");
  }*/


  //console.log("** " + message + " **");
});
```

When the function chat.on is called a variable of message with a string is supposed to run through the switch statement, I have an array with different strings and if the message includes a string from that array, run the case. But nothing happens, it all seems right what could be wrong here?

Comment: Read the documentation for `switch` more closely.

Answer (score 3):

One way to solve this problem is by using switch(true) instead of switch(method). This will work since then it will compare true(boolean) with the case statements. The Case Statement which includes emote[0] will be returning true, thus it will go ahead and execute that block. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

switch doesn't work in the way you expect. It takes the value written in switch and compares with each in the case blocks. So in your case it will compare true/false with the value message, and it won't find the same value and as a result nothing will happen. 
You have to use if else statements or parse the message and exclude the value like
Message 'type/emote1'
Extract everything afte slash and put it in the switch

Comment: I basically want to check the string `message` and if the string `mesage` has `emote[0]` included, run the case statement. Im using a switch statement because i have to do this about 50 more times, at the moment I just have 4 but i will be adding 46 after i know it works.